# How to read a CSV file stored in a byte array, in order to generate checksum?

Tags: java, arrays, maven

Here's the situation, I wrote a code to convert the CSV file(with information in it) into a ByteArray and to a String and stored it in the DB. Right now I need to generate the checksum for the said file without doing it manually. Now here's my question(there are a few actually):

1.)Is it literally possible to take in the ByteArray to generate the checksum?

2.)If so for (1), then why is my ByteArray different everytime I run the program even though I did not change anything(nor add any value) in the CSV file?

Or are there any better approaches in tackling this task? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public void main(){
            // prepare the workbook
            Workbook reportWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            List<CellStyle> styles = initializeAllCellStyle(reportWorkbook);

            // Write Tap On Phone Sheet
            writeDataToSheet(reportWorkbook, styles, monthStart, monthEnd, year);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                reportWorkbook.write(bos);
            } finally {
                bos.close();
            }

            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

            Date today = new Date();
            String strYearMonth = yyyy + MM;
            String xlsxCopyInBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
            Report bReport = new Report();

            byte[] shaInBytes = ReportServiceImpl.digest(bytes, "SHA-256");
                 bReport.setBillingReport(EncryptionUtil.doAESEncrypt(xlsxCopyInBase64, "123",EncryptionUtil.HEX));
                 bReport.setCreatedBy("MANUAL");
                 bReport.setCreatedDate(today);
                 bReport.setReportDate(strYearMonth);
                 mobileDAO.saveToDB(bReport);
                 //Just to print out and test the checksum
                logger.info(String.format(OUTPUT_FORMAT, "SHA-256" + "(hex)", bytesToHex(shaInBytes)));

}

public static byte[] digest(byte[] input, String algorithm) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
        byte[] result = md.digest(input);
        md.reset();
        return result;
    }

public static String bytesToHexes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: In theory it is possible so your question deserves a 'yes' as answer. But I do not get why CSV is involved at all. You have a sequence of bytes, and you want to checksum that. It should be regardless where you load the checksum from: a file or the DB are expected to bring the same result in your case. So I still do not get where you have the problem?

Comment: hi @HiranChaudhuri, thanks for answering that and clearing it up, in the end I just took a random string of line inside the file to generated the checksum instead. Oh ya and the file was a xlsx file(not CSV, my bad),so I was having problems not generating the constant checksum that I wanted due to having to deal with the styles cause it was  a .xlsx file.